# Need help running 2 queries in a Cursor PLSQL

Tags: variables, plsql, cursor, records, sys-refcursor

I'm new to PLSQL and need to run one of either 2 queries based of the user input.  I created this so far...

```
 Set serveroutput on;
 Declare
 cv_prod SYS_REFCURSOR;
 rec_d dd_pledge%ROWTYPE;
 rec_s dd_pledge%ROWTYPE;
 userinput varchar(1):='&Enter';


 Begin
 If lower(userinput)= 'd' THEN
     OPEN cv_prod FOR Select dd_payment.idpay, dd_pledge.idpledge, dd_pledge.iddonor, dd_payment.paydate, pledgeamt/paymonths 
       from dd_pledge
         join dd_payment
           on dd_pledge.idpledge=dd_payment.idpledge
             where iddonor=308
               order by idpay, dd_pledge.iddonor;
   LOOP
     FETCH cv_prod into rec_d;
       EXIT WHEN cv_prod%NOTFOUND;
         --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_d);
   END LOOP;
 ELSIF lower(userinput)= 's' THEN
     OPEN cv_prod FOR Select dd_pledge.idpledge, sum(pledgeamt/paymonths)
       from dd_pledge
         join dd_payment
           on dd_pledge.idpledge=dd_payment.idpledge
             where iddonor=308
               group by dd_pledge.idpledge;
     LOOP
       FETCH cv_prod into rec_s;
         EXIT WHEN cv_prod%NOTFOUND;
           --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_s);
     END LOOP;
 END IF;
```

End;
So the error that I'm getting is the return types of result set variables or query do not match.  I don't get it because my records or baskets should have the same row type as the table the columns are coming from.  Please help!

Edited Declare statement for records...
 Declare

```
 cv_prod SYS_REFCURSOR;
 type rec_d is Record(idpay dd_payment.idpay%type, idpledge dd_pledge.idpledge%type, iddonor dd_pledge.iddonor%type, paydate dd_payment.paydate%type);
 cv prod rec_d;
 type rec_s is Record(pledge dd_pledge.idpledge%type)
 cv_prod rec_s
 rec_s dd_pledge%ROWTYPE;
 userinput varchar(1):='&Enter';
```

Got to be close... New code.
--Donor ID = 308
 /* Lucas Gutknecht Chapter 4 */

```
Set serveroutput on;
 Declare
 cv_prod SYS_REFCURSOR;
 type rec_d is Record(idpay dd_payment.idpay%type, idpledge dd_pledge.idpledge%type, iddonor dd_pledge.iddonor%type, paydate dd_payment.paydate%type);
 rec_d1 rec_d;
 type rec_s is Record(pledge dd_pledge.idpledge%type);
rec_s1 rec_s;
 userinput varchar(1):='&Enter';


 Begin
 If lower(userinput)= 'd' THEN
     OPEN cv_prod FOR Select dd_payment.idpay, dd_pledge.idpledge, dd_pledge.iddonor, dd_payment.paydate /*pledgeamt/paymonths*/ 
       from dd_pledge
         join dd_payment
           on dd_pledge.idpledge=dd_payment.idpledge
             where iddonor=308
               order by idpay, dd_pledge.iddonor;
   LOOP
     FETCH cv_prod into rec_d1;
       EXIT WHEN cv_prod%NOTFOUND;
         --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_d);
   END LOOP;
 ELSIF lower(userinput)= 's' THEN
     OPEN cv_prod FOR Select dd_pledge.idpledge, /*sum(pledgeamt/paymonths)*/
       from dd_pledge
         join dd_payment
           on dd_pledge.idpledge=dd_payment.idpledge
             where iddonor=308
               group by dd_pledge.idpledge;
     LOOP
       FETCH cv_prod into rec_s1;
         EXIT WHEN cv_prod%NOTFOUND;
           --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_s);
     END LOOP;
 END IF;
 End
```

;

Comment: What does the table dd_pledge look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first cursor, you are selecting 5 columns -

```
OPEN cv_prod FOR Select dd_payment.idpay, dd_pledge.idpledge, dd_pledge.iddonor, dd_payment.paydate, pledgeamt/paymonths
```

In the second cursor, you are only selecting 2 columns -

```
OPEN cv_prod FOR Select dd_pledge.idpledge, sum(pledgeamt/paymonths)
```

Both these cursors are fetched into a variable of the same type which is `dd_pledge%ROWTYPE;`.

Either the table has 5 columns or 2. Based on the structure of the table `dd_pledge` change the cursor which is not returning the same number of columns as the base table to do that.

If however you are selecting different data, I'd advise creating two separate procedures for this or create the two record variables with different datatypes that match their respective cursor.

Comment: Thank you that does make sense.  Is it possible to create two records that have different columns and data types using one cursor?  I need to run both queries in one cursor.  How would I do that?  My understanding of cursors is vague.

Comment: You can't "run" both queries in a cursor. Cursor is a pointer to a single SQL area. You can reassign the pointer to point to a different sql after you are done with the first. I'd recommend reading [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html) for some basics.

Comment: I meant to say only run one query at a time but have the option of running two different based off of the users input.  Wouldn't the cursor only be ran once depending on "s" or "d" is entered and wouldn't that cursor take on the same type as where the information is coming from?

Comment: The cursor is just a pointer. A weak cursor like this one, can point to a query with 1 column or a query with 100 columns. This is irrelevant to how many columns any of the base tables have. The problem is the FETCH statement. When you fetch 1 row from this cursor into a variable, that variable should have the same number of columns as what the cursor is pointing to. In your case, you have defined the variable as `rec_d dd_pledge%ROWTYPE;` and `rec_s dd_pledge%ROWTYPE;`. Both these variables take the format of a row in the table `dd_pledge`

Comment: What you might want to do is to create another record-type variable (look up `CREATE TYPE ... AS RECORD ... `) and then fetch the results of the cursor into that variable.

Comment: Thank you for all the help.  I can't upvote yet but will mark as completed.  This is what I came up with.. Ruudvan please see edited section and give me some pointers.

Comment: You have the type declaration down but you are declaring the same variables twice. Let's see the datatype of each variable - `cv_prod` is a cursor so `SYS_REFCURSOR`. `rec_d` is now a new datatype as a record. So create a new variable for that datatype. `cv_prod` is not of the type of a record. It has already been declared as a cursor. So take out the statements that say `cv_prod rec_d;`